# PHP/MySQL Find all groupids from user_to_group table

Tags: php, mysql

I habe this Database:

```
db: users
userID | username
1 | user1
2 | user2
3 | user3

db: group
groupID | groupName
1 | Admin
2 | Moderator
3 | Guest
4 | VIP

db: user_to_grouo
userID | groupID
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 4
2 | 2
2 | 4
3 | 4
```

and one Variable with a Array of userID. Now I want a result with all GroupIDs where all userID are in.

Two examples with result:

```
$userIDs = array(1,2,3); //Result: 4

$userIDs = array(1,2); //Result: 2, 4
```

How can I find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
    $array=array(1,2,3);
    $count=  count($array);

    $query="select groupId from user_to_group where userId in (".  implode(',', $array).") group by 
            groupId having count(groupId) =".$count;
```